# Dapper parameterised queries with LINQ autogenerated types

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I'm using a combination of LINQ and Dapper in my work.  I'm replacing my LINQ code with Dapper in places for performance reasons.  I have a lot of LINQ data objects created by dragging and dropping into the Visual Studio database diagram from SQL Server.

In the following instance I already have a LINQ object in memory and I'd like to pass it to Dapper as the parameters for a query.  For example:

```
Animal animal = con.Query<Animal>(" select * " +
        " from animal " +
        " where animalid = @AnimalId " +
        " and animaltype = @AnimalType ",
        cagedAnimal).SingleOrDefault();
```

cagedAnimal contains a public properties AnimalId and AnimalType with getters and setters.

However on executing this code I get the following error:

> The type : SMDApp.Models.Animal is
>   not supported by dapper

The following code does work:

```
Animal animal = con.Query<Animal>(" select * " +
            " from animal " +
            " where animalid = @AnimalId " +
            " and animaltype = @AnimalType ",
            new 
            { 
            AnimalId = cagedAnimal.AnimalId, 
            AnimalType = cagedAnimal.AnimalType 
            }
            ).SingleOrDefault();
```

It'd be more convenient for me to use an existing object particularly where I'm using more than one property of the object as a parameter for the query.  Can anybody tell my why this works for an anonymous object but not an auto generated LINQ object?

Edited in response to Ben Robinson's reply.

Edited a second time in response to Marc Gravell's reply.

Comment: are you *sure* you are doing `"...", cagedAnimal)` ? are you perhaps doing `"...", new { cagedAnimal })` instead? basically - that should already work, although it is a bit wasteful in that additional parameters might be added unnecessarily/

Comment: just to let you know that I just pushed a fix that would a: ignore any properties that aren't used in your query, and b: give a much better error message when it *does* struggle. I haven't deployed to nuget, but with the new code your example above should work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version is *that should already work*; based on the error:

> The type : SMDApp.Models.CagedAnimal is not supported by dapper

I conclude that either you are actually passing `new {cagedAnimal}` instead of `cagedAnimal`, *or*, your `CagedAnimal` has a property (`Parent`, perhaps?) that is itself a `CagedAnimal`, and which dapper can't understand. The current behaviour is that a parameter is added ***for every public property*** of the provided parameter object - and if it can't figure out how to send any of the properties to the database, it complains. You should find that a simple POCO with just value members works fine.

However! Note that it does not ever attempt to parse your SQL - in particular, it does not check for parameters in the query provided. As such, using the POCO approach will mean that you are adding unnecessary properties to the query.

We use dapper extensively, and we just use the approach:

```
 new { obj.Foo, obj.Bar, id, key = "something else" }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc that's it.  I misread the error message.  Doh!  You still somehow got the correct answer.  I've edited the error message in the question now.  The CagedAnimal class had a property of type Animal which Dapper didn't understand.

Comment: @Giles we are planning to change the error message to include the name of the property(/parameter) it is choking on - so your question has led to a positive change / outcome ;p

Comment: @Giles we are *also* discussing whether or not to pre-filter the properties we send based on the command, i.e. only send `param.foo` if we can see `@foo` or `:foo` in the command-text, which would remove the "unnecessary parameters" issue

Comment: @Marc It did give me the name of the property it was choking on.  It's just that my brain somehow mistranslated it internally to CagedAnimal because Animal was the same as the result type of the query statement.  It would be nice if you could do the stripping of the unnecessary parameters as I believe that would allow my original code to work.  Obviously not at the expense of performance though.  BTW Dapper is so much faster than LINQ so thanks very much for publishing it.

Comment: @Giles - the version in google-code *does* that stripping. And it didn't used to display the member-name, AFAIK - just the *type* name. Of course, if that is a coincidental match?

Comment: @Giles, be sure to grab latest and read my answer, this issue is now "fixed"

Comment: @Sam, you're were right about the string matching / regex being tricky.  It doesn't work in this case.    @Marc the IndexOf("@" + prop.Name, ... on line 907 of SqlMapper.cs matches the property Animal of CagedAnimal against @AnimalId and @AnimalType in the sql string.  So it now throws the more informative error message.

Comment: @Giles yeah, I noted that false positive risk earlier. I plan on improving this later

Comment: @Giles ... can you try latest, I think it should work as expected now

Comment: @Sam - Thanks a lot.  Latest works as expected.  BTW loving the profiler from a slow day on stack overflow too.

Answer (score 3):

Marc just committed a change to [fix for this issue](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/diff?spec=svnce48dce394419de7e232284bff0a4bca5bb47fb0&r=ce48dce394419de7e232284bff0a4bca5bb47fb0&format=side&path=/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) in particular:

1. We perform a trivial validation before sending attempting to translate properties to params. For example Dapper will not not send any params to the server for this case: cnn.Query("select 1", new {bla = 1}) cause "bla" does not exist in the string. This validation is skipped for stored procs.
2. The error, which was rather cryptic, is now fixed and much improved.

--

Dapper used to perform no parsing of the underlying SQL statement, so for example:

```
@"select * 
from animal
where animalid = @AnimalId"
```

Contains a single param called `@AnimalId`.

It gets complicated cause, to be 100% correct you need to handle edge cases EG: `@AnimalId` into the string `select '@AnimalId' -- @AnimalId \* @AnimalId *\`? The regex does get a bit tricky, I have not thought through every edge case. For example: Oracle prefixes its params with a `:` which complicates things more.

Since dapper knew nothing about the params in the string, it decided to send in **every** public property as a parameter. Some of your public properties can not be mapped to `DbParameters` so it complained.