# Dapper model mapping

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, data-mapping

I've been playing with [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and I have a question. Is there a way for me to be able to have an enumerator type property in my POCO class and use Dapper? Seems like every time I add a property which is of type Enumerator I get the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: The type : *my_enum_type* is not
>   supported by dapper

Am I missing something here? Is there an attribute that I can attach to these properties to specify which of them are mapping to database table columns?

Comment: Do you actually mean `IEnumerator` (unlikely) or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: I mean Enum type... Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old bug in dapper, ensure you use the latest version. Dapper used to perform no filtering on the input types properties.

<strike>Ok I figured this out and it was my fault for not seeing this in the 1st place. This is what I was doing initially:</strike>

```
Dim result = conn.Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID", New User With {.UserID = userID})
```

But what needed to be done is:

```
Dim result = conn.Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID", New With {.UserID = userID})
```

In other words declaring param as anonymous type is essential. If you declare param as a specific type and that type contains a property of type which is not covered by dapper code (such as Enum) then the code crashes with the above mentioned error. My User class had an Enum type property and it was causing the problem.

Comment: Im not sure about this, can you confirm you have issues using latest dapper and real types, I already implemented a bunch of param stripping

Comment: in particular see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520128/dapper-parameterised-queries-with-linq-autogenerated-types/6520421#6520421

Comment: You are correct, I compiled a new dll using the latest version of the code and it fixed the issue. Last time I did this was more than a month ago. Sorry for the trouble...